# Noise (from autofocus?) during Video on DSLR

Tags: microphone, noise

I have a Canon 6D Mark II and am shooting video with a Canon EW-83H lens. The videos come out great but are plagued by audible creaking and clicking sounds during playback. My guess is that this noise is due to autofocus of the lens. I tried two other lenses (one prime and one telephoto) but both basically have the same issue. The camera is brand new but the lenses are not (but in good condition).

Is this an issue with my set up in particular or is the always an issue with shooting a video with a DSLR and a lens with autofocus + IS? What's the recommended solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noise you talk about is usually caused by lens motors related to autofocus and motors, related to image stabilization. The best you can do is to use external microphone and connect it to microphone port of the camera. This will give you better isolation of the recorded sound from camera noises and better sound quality.

Of course you can always use external sound recorder and sync video and sound in post.

EDIT: to avoid the noise from focus motors you can use manual focus. To avoid noise from stabilization motors (if any) you can switch off image stabilization (VR, OS, IS or whatever it is named) and use rig with stabilization or tripod.

Comment: Thanks, Romeo. Do you think an external mic that's mounted on top of the camera will solve this issue? Also, is this a typical problem for most people with my general setup?

Comment: @Kulluk007, it depends if the microphone will be unidirectional or omnidirectional. In general the first type will be less sensitive to the sound/noise which is not on the direction where mic point. If it's typical: I think yes and that's the reason of extensive usage of external mics or recorders.